# Mongoose embedded documents / Object { size: {} } has no method cast

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I like to Embedded a document in another document.
here my first mongoose document witch include the second one "grille": 
chp_bat.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId
  , Grille = require('../models/grille');

function validatePresenceOf(value) {
  return value && value.length;
}

var Chp_bat = new Schema({
  name : { type: String, validate: [validatePresenceOf, 'a chp_bat is required'] },
  avatar : { type: String },
  description : { type: String },
  grille : [Grille],
  created_at : Date,
  updated_at : Date
});
var Chp_bat = mongoose.model('Chp_bat', Chp_bat);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Chp_bat', Chp_bat);
```

My second document: grille.js

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;


function validatePresenceOf(value) {
  return value && value.length;
}

var Grille = new Schema({
  name : { type: String, validate: [validatePresenceOf, 'a grille is required'] },
  avatar : { type: String },
  description : { type: String },
  size : { x: Number, y: Number },
  created_at : Date,
  updated_at : Date
});
var Grille = mongoose.model('Grille', Grille);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Grille', Grille);
```

my routes:

```
var User = require('../../models/user')
  , Chp_bat = require('../../models/chp_bat')
  , Grille = require('../../models/grille');

module.exports = function (app){

/*
 * GET New chp_bat.
 */
  app.get('/chp_bat_new', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res){
      Grille.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        res.render('chp_bat/new', {
          docs: docs,
      user : req.user,
      title : ' Que voulez vous créer Maitre Du Jeu'
        });
      });
    });


/*
 * POST New chp_bat.
 */
  app.post('/maitre-chp_bat-new', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res){
    var chp_bat = new Chp_bat();
    chp_bat.name = req.body.name;
    chp_bat.avatar = req.body.avatar;
    chp_bat.description = req.body.description;
    chp_bat.grille.push(req.body.grille);
    chp_bat.created_at = new Date();
    chp_bat.save(function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        res.redirect('/maitre-chp_bat-new');
        console.log(req.body);
      }
      else {
        res.redirect('/maitre-chp_bat-new');
      }
    });
    });



};
```

I obtain this error: Object { size: {} } has no method 'cast'
I thought I was good, making same things like mongoose docs and I dont understand what I didn't do well.

====

So, like always when you post the question the answer come.
I write it for other people:

When you write the doc embedded include the _id like this:

```
grille: [Grille._id],
```

So easy.

Answer (score 0):

for chaining your docs together consider doing something like this:

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    require('./routes')(app);
}
console.log('Listening on port 8888');
```

routes/index.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var Users = require('../controllers/users')(app);
    app.get('/logout',Users.profile);
}
```

controllers/users.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var User = require('../models/users')(app),

    return {
        profile: function (req, res) {
            User.findOne(
                {'email' : 'your@email.com'},
                '_id name email modifiedOn',
                function(err, user) {
                    if (!err) {
                        //do something with user
                    } else {
                        res.send({"error": "some error happened"});
                    }
                }
            );
        },
        login: function(req,res){
            //login to login here.  you know like req.body.email and req.body.password etc.
        }
    }
}
```

models/users.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
var db = require('../lib/db')(app);

var userSchema = new db.Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String, 
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdOn: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now
    },
    modifiedOn: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now
    },
    lastLogin: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now
    }
});
db.model( 'User', userSchema);

return db.model('User');
}
```

lib/db.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var uri = 'mongodb://'+app.get('db_host')+':'+app.get('db_port')+'/'+app.get('db_database');
    var options = {}
    mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    mongoose.connection.on('connected', console.log.bind(console, 'Mongoose connected to ' + uri));
    mongoose.connection.on('error',console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', console.log.bind('Mongoose disconnected'));

    process.on('SIGINT', function() {
        mongoose.connection.close(function () {
            console.log('Mongoose disconnected through app termination');
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
    return mongoose;
}
```

Note that in this example I am using config items for db_host, port, and database.  Personally this setup works great for me.  Comes in handy when your app gets larger too.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because of

```
chp_bat.grille.push(req.body.grille);
```